# Matrix inequality that follows from other inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have the following inequality:

$$
f(x)^T(f(x) - A x) \leq 0
$$

The $A$ is a positive definite matrix of dimension $a \times a$, $x$ is a $a \times 1$ vector and $f$ is a vector valued function that has $a$ dimensions (everything real valued). Why follows from this:

$$
f(x)^T(A^{-1}f(x) - x) \leq 0 
$$

I can't multiply $A^{-1}$ from the left side because the $f(x)^T$ is in the way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. E.g. let
$$
x=\pmatrix{1\\ 1},\ f(x)=\pmatrix{1\\ -1},\ A=\pmatrix{4&0\\ 0&1}.
$$
Then
\begin{aligned}
f(x)^T(f(x)-Ax)&=\pmatrix{1&-1}\left[\pmatrix{1\\ -1}-\pmatrix{4\\ 1}\right]
=\pmatrix{1&-1}\pmatrix{-3\\ -2}=-1<0,\\
f(x)^T(A^{-1}f(x)-x)&=\pmatrix{1&-1}\left[\pmatrix{\frac14\\ -1}-\pmatrix{1\\ 1}\right]
=\pmatrix{1&-1}\pmatrix{-\frac34\\ -2}=\frac54>0.
\end{aligned}

Comment: Ok thank you. Is maybe the converse true?

Comment: @user3137490 No, the converse isn't true. I think the original question has either typos or some missing conditions. E.g. as a deleted answer suggests, there is perhaps contains a typo: it probably reads $f(x)^T\color{red}{A}(A^{-1}f(x)-x)\le0$.

Comment: I have checked again and it should be like I wrote (no typo). The only other conditions are that $f$ is differentiable and that the inequality must be true for all $x$ but I am not sure if it changes anything...